# What is the difference between 旅する and 旅行する?

Tags: word-choice

**旅{たび}する** and **旅行{りょこう}する** both mean "to travel". 
What is the difference between these verbs ?

Comment: The difference is bigger than you seem to think because only one of the two words (旅 and 旅行) can be used to say something like "Life is a journey."

Comment: I would compare them with "to take a trip" or "to journey" and "to travel." 
Worthy of note is that one is native kun-yomi 訓読み (旅する) and the other is Chinese-derived on-yomi 音読み. On-yomi words tend to be more technical/formal. It would be odd for a fairy-tale character to 旅行する; likewise, it would be odd to have 旅（たび）会社 instead of a 旅行会社.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you point out, the basic meaning of "to travel" is contained in both words, but the context in which they would be used is very different.

> **旅する** - to go on a journey, to sojourn

インドを長く**旅している**と、段々心が広くなった。

- As we **journeyed** through India, our hearts gradually opened up.

*(probably something you would read in a novel or story)*

> **旅行する** - to take a vacation

来年家族とインドに**旅行する**ことを考えている。

- I'm thinking of **taking a vacation** to India with my family next year.

*(probably something you would overhear somebody say in real life)*